# Use href then execute a PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As a disclaimer, I'm quite new to web development and even before I posted this, I have spent hours looking for answers but everything I have read did not help on what I want to do.

I'm basically trying to redirect to a certain page and then execute a php function which also require a variable to be pass to it and is inside a class.

I've read about ajax but people have said that theres no point using it if I want to redirect to another page anyway as its only good to use if you just want to reload a portion of the page.

The most simplistic way I can explain on what I want to do is, when I click on an image, I would like for a new page to be open and then in that said page is all the things about that image. For example, description about it, a short vid and maybe a comment section regarding the image clicked.

Please explain if what I'm trying to do is not possible and if so, please point me in the right direction as to what might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Paste your code what you have tried.

Comment: Please don't feed the caribou.

Comment: *Try* writing some code *1st*, and *learn*. 
If after [**researching this**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) and experienced some difficulties, post what you tried 
along with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** & provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. 
[Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [**this**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937), then edit your question respectively; we'll be glad to take a **L@@K** at it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just link to a php page and pass a request variable.

```
<a href="myPage.php?someVar=someValue">Link</a>

// myPage.php
<?php echo($_REQUEST['someVar']); ?>
```

This will output "someValue" on the new page.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've managed to changed a few things to achieve what I wanted with the help of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

here's a really simple example:`

```
<a href="test.php?id=21" title="Image description"> <img src="test_image.png" alt="your alt"> </a>  <!-- Simple link with a id attribute -->
```

`

On the PHP side:

```
image_infos($_GET['id']);           //Call the PHP function with the image ID

function image_infos($id)
{
    //Get your infos from the Server or whatever
}
```